# Ajax-запрос

Tags: ajax, php

Не получается выполнить ajax запрос. Вот [пример из книги](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_K88/MYxc5/#base)

Как  подключить файл "getUpdatedBoardSales-ajax.php" или же его надо загрузить на сервер? Сервера у меня нету. Что в этом примере я неправильно делаю?

Comment: > Сервера у меня нету

А к чему вы планируете делать ajax запрос в таком случае?

Comment: поставь OpenServer.

Comment: Файл getUblablabal-ajax.php исполняется на сервере. То есть там, где стоит апач с модулем php.  
Вам совершенно не обязательно покупать какой-нибудь пролиант для этого. В учебных целях можете скачать Денвер (ищите в яндексе по этому магическому слову).

Comment: Спс. Для начала попробую второй вариант

Comment: `php -S` работает в винде?

Answer (score 1):

> Сервера у меня нету

Тогда что Вы делаете? Как Вы планируете работать с php не имея сервера? И куда ajax запросы слать?
Поставьте себе OPENSERVER https://ospanel.io на комп и учитесь полноценно. Там простой инсталлер в два клика, о серверах можно вообще ничего не знать. Без него или подобных виртуальных серверов будет тяжко Вам постигать web.